# Excel: dynamic ranges with offset function vs. all range selection (A:A), processing efficiency

Tags: excel

I am trying in my Excel file to optimise computation efficiency within conditional formulas.

Which option is the most efficient:

- Name a dynamic range (that will be used as the range argument in a `COUNTIF` function) through the `OFFSET` function

OR

- Selecting the whole column by default (ex: "`C:C`" as the range argument).

In other terms, is it better to have a dynamic range or to have the formula computing on a whole column?

Comment: Offset is volatile and should be avoided.  With COUNTIF there is no detriment to full column references.  Full column references should be avoided in array type formula.   Instead of Offset use INDEX instead.

Comment: Convert the range to a table and just refer to the rows in the table and never look back.